# Cell.Address function with Index and Match function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the address of the cell by using this formula through VBA.
=CELL("address",INDEX(A:C,MATCH(2019,A1:A124,0),3)) and the result I get is the absolute address of the cell.

I think I did something wrongly and it doesn't work.I have multiple sheets in the workbook so it is located at Sheet5.

```
Dim x As String
Dim year As String
year = 2019
 x = Sheet5.Cells.Address(WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet5.Range("A:C"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(year, Sheet5.Range("A1:A124"), 0), 3))
```

Please help thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking up your code a bit: it's not great to do too much in one line.

```vba
Dim m, yr

yr = 2019

'note no `WorksheetFunction`
m = Application.Match(yr, sheet5.Range("A1:A124"), 0) 'edit year>>yr

If Not IsError(m) Then
    MsgBox sheet5.Cells(m, "C").Address
Else
    MsgBox "No match for " & yr
End If
```

Comment: A error pops out at m = Application.Match(year, Sheet5.Range("A1:A124"), 0)
I should define m as a variant right?

Comment: Yes `m` should be a variant.  Missed an edit above year >> yr

Comment: There is error when returning m. What could be the possible error? It should be able to get the address. I tried the same formula on the sheet and it works

Comment: Working for me.  Make sure not to declare `yr` as String.